# How to output single character text with php?

Tags: php, apache, echo, plaintext

I am implementing an API for some service that should return in the content only one character like '0' or '1' with no trailing or leading spaces or html tags.

I tried the following.

```
header( 'Content-Type:text/plain' );
echo "1";
```

and

```
header( 'Content-Type:text/plain' );
print "1";
```

I also tried to omit the header line, but I always get a new line character at the end of the output.

This is the output of php -v.

```
PHP 5.3.28 (cli) (built: Dec 15 2013 17:43:05)
Copyright (c) 1997-2013 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2013 Zend Technologies
```

This is the output of httpd -v

```
Server version: Apache/2.2.23 (Unix)
Server built:   Nov 25 2012 15:00:50
```

Comment: And do you have `?>` anywhere in your code?

Comment: Yes I have ?> at the end of the code. Shall I omit it?

Comment: If there's a newline or any space after the `?>`, then it would explain your problem.... so, yes, remove it... it's often a good idea not to use `?>` at all unless you explicitly wish to switch to direct output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only this much code in a file will help :)

```
<?php echo 1;
```

Comment: Thank you very much, but unfortunately I am still getting the new line character when I look at the page source.

Comment: It worked with omitting ?> from the code. Thank you very much.